# Can you create default product attributes

Tags: templates, attributes, woocommerce, product

I am trying to create a store of products with WooCommerce and would like, if possible, to simplify the process of adding new products by having a default set of attributes.

For example, all of my products share certain attributes including: volts, watts, colour temperature etc. I have created these attributes and can select them when I add a new product but it would be really useful, for consistency and speed, if every time I added a product of a certain category the Add Product page automatically added a given set of attributes, rather than me having to add each attribute one by one for every product I add.

Does anyone know if this is possible?